# How could I show a row from the database to a textbox in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, mdf

I just started with Visual Studio and I was wondering on how could I echo out the first row under the `maincategory_name` column of my `maincategory` table to the textbox1. I followed a guide on how to insert data through the database but what I wanted to know is how could I print out one so I'm kinda confused how will I be able to do it as for know, the output I get on my textbox is: `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand`

```
namespace TrialForDatabase
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename='C:\\Users\\flex\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\Inventory\\Inventory\\inventory.mdf';Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
    SqlCommand cmd;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sc.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT maincategory_name FROM maincategory", sc);
        textBox1.Text = cmd.ToString();
        sc.Close();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: SqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

Comment: You are printing name of `cmd` variable type. You should **execute** command, get results from sql server and only then display results in textbox. I suggest you to search for tutorials on querying sql server in C#

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot I had to query sql statements to get something out of them. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function first creates your SQL command, the executes it using SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(), then checks if you got any results using SqlDataReader.Read(), then displays the first column of the first row of your result to the Textbox:

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       sc.Open();
       cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT maincategory_name FROM maincategory", sc);
       using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()){
           if ( reader.Read() )
           {
              textBox1.Text = reader.GetString(0);
           }
       };

       sc.Close();
   }
```

See here for some more info on the classes used:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

`ToString()` more often that not is not redefined from `Object`, so it only prints the class's name.

What you want to do is print the **result** of your SQL command, and to do so, you will need... well, to execute it.

[SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will return a [SQLDataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object, from which you can read rows like you would with a simple array.

So if you really only want the first row, you could get away with a quick and dirty:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sc.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT maincategory_name FROM maincategory", sc);
    textBox1.Text = cmd.ExecuteReader()[0];
    sc.Close();
}
```